# How do I find out the meaning of index in a .shp or .shx shapefile?

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas

```py
import geopandas as gpd    

DATA = gpd.read_file('Africa.shx')
DATA.info()
```

I have two shapefiles downloaded from [this website](https://open.africa/bg/dataset/africa-shapefiles), `Africa.shx` and `Africa.shp`. **How do I know which countries are included?** For example, the index goes from 0 to 58, but Africa only has 55 countries (West Sahara counted). Also, **how should I match data from each country to a shapefile?** I think it's also done by the index, so very important to find out what they mean. BTW, **which filetype is more convenient to deal with for such matching job**, `.shx` or `.shp`?

```
<class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 59 entries, 0 to 58
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype   
---  ------    --------------  -----   
 0   geometry  59 non-null     geometry
dtypes: geometry(1)
memory usage: 600.0 bytes
```

Comment: You need `Africa.dbf` file for that. That is where data like names are stored. If you have `shp, `shx` and `dbf` in one folder, then `gpd.read_file('Africa.shp')` should load it all correctly.

Comment: @martinfleis Thank you! It didn't work because I changed the long file name to `Africa`... Didn't know `.dbf` is important. Now it's all fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @martinfleis You can turn it to an answer and I'll accept it, if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `Africa.dbf` file for that. That is where data like names are stored. If you have `shp`, `shx` and `dbf` in one folder, then `gpd.read_file('Africa.shp')` should load it all correctly.